# Explorer view of files stored in txt file

Tags: java, swing, icons

I am newbie to this part of Java Programming. 
I have few files which are stored in .txt. Now I am fetching this files and displaying in table. There's no problem with that.

What I want is to display files in .txt as something like thumnails (i.e there are few files of .mp3, .pdf etc mixed in .txt file) and I want to display them with there associated icon which is of course not possible in `JTable`. I want to know through which component that's possible and some code for it to get me started. Please this helps me a lot.

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for use of good icons in a tree ..and a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display them with there associated icon

You can get the system Icon with code like the following:

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(...));
```

> which is of course not possible in JTable.

Then you just add the `Icon` to the `TableModel` and make sure to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method so the table will use the appropriate renderer for the Icon.

Edit:

> i am not able to set that sort of font to each coloumn

A JTable uses a renderer. You can customize the renderer easily or create a completely new renderer. For example:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
centerRenderer.setFont(...);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for that!! I'll try it but list contents viewed in the table are in the form of a list which is not so "user-friendly". Is there a different component which has a cleaner view of files with there icons.

Comment: `not so "user-friendly".` how is it not user friendly? `Is there a different component which has a cleaner view of files with there icons` Maybe you want a `JList` which can display the list items in a grid, or `JTree` which will give you directory/file structure.

Comment: No offense to u sir but using JTable with more than 10-15 rows is not looking good and hence was asking for a different component. Jtree will not work as it takes a lot of space if there are more files sir. I'll try with the JList and come back to you. Thank U once again!

Comment: `using JTable with more than 10-15 rows is not looking good` Why? Have you ever used Windows Explorer in "Detail View". My Java directory has 100's of files. This is a very common UI.

Comment: Yes sir. Explorer view in windows is good( because Only name column dark font and other details like Location and size are of light font). But with Jtable i am not able to set that sort of font to each coloumn. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: *"But with Jtable i am not able to set that sort of font to each coloumn."*  I (and most other developers) can!

Comment: Thank u sir. Wil try with that new code and come back to you tomorrow.